# Image segmentation with OpenCV - Entire image being considered a segment

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am writing code that extracts text from an image (a document, in this particular scenario). Before doing so, I am running the usual image-processing tasks of binarization and segmentation in order to identify where exactly in the image I can find the bits of text.

It's all working relatively perfectly, save for one detail: among the segments I get from OpenCV there is one segment that is the image itself. Therefore, I am extracting the text from the image twice: once from every bit of text (that is, the correctly identified segments) and once from the whole image (that is, the incorrectly identified segment).

Sadly, I can't post the image for privacy issues, as it is a birth certificate, but my question is: how can I stop the image itself from being considered as one of the segments?

Here's how I am getting the segments following binarization and dilation:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

And here is my pretty straightforward text-extraction loop:

```
text = ''

for contour in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    image_segment = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    text += pytesseract.image_to_string(image_segment, lang='eng') + '\n'
```

I came up with a solution that involves comparing the contour's boundaries with the image's boundaries, and ignoring that segment in the loop if they are the same. But that doesn't seem like the ideal solution.

Comment: Invert the binarized image.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Here's what I did, if other folks are having the same problem:

1. I inverted the binarized image with cv2.bitwise_not.

2. Instead of dilating the text, I eroded it. So I got black "blots" instead of white "blots" where the text was.

3. I inverted the dilated image with cv2.bitwise_not.

4. I used cv2.findContours.

Comment: @DanMašek, why did that work exactly, by the way?

Comment: In the first stage, `findContours` looks for white things surrounded by black (objects). The area outside the bounds of the image is considered to be black, so if you have an image with white background, the top-level object will be the whole image. You explicitly asked it to give you only the **external** contour (i.e. the top-level object), so you got it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.